# How to suppress part of the output from `lapply()`?

Tags: r

I want to use `lapply()` to print all the elements that I have inside of a list. The following code does that, but the output produced is strange.

```
N.seq <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
lapply(N.seq,print)
```

What I get from `R` looks like this.

```
[1] 1
[1] 2
[1] 3
[1] 4
[1] 5
[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
[1] 2

[[3]]
[1] 3

[[4]]
[1] 4

[[5]]
[1] 5
```

How can I get `lapply()` to only print each thing in the list once?

Comment: You need `as.list(N.seq)`

Comment: If all you need is the *side-effect*, then it serves you little good to use `lapply`, it might be more direct and clear if you do `for (x in N.seq) print(x)`. The `*apply` family of functions can be used for side-effect stuff but is better fit for functional (no-side-effect) use, where you need to capture a list of the same length as the input.

Comment: But an alternative to @akrun's `invisible` is to save it to an unused variable, such as `ign <- lapply(...)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `*apply`s always return something, so `lapply` will print everything and then give you some output. What you want is called a [side effect](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/r-in-a/9781449358204/ch09s06.html), which is when the function affects things outside of its own local scope. You could enclose your `*apply` functions in `invisible()` to suppress the output, but the purrr package has a function designed explicitly to handle side effects:

```r
library(purrr)
walk(N.seq, print)

#### OUTPUT ####

[1] 1
[1] 2
[1] 3
[1] 4
[1] 5
```

Comment: I like this more because I typically have `purrr()` loaded anyway and this looks a lot more elegant to me.

Comment: Every call returns something, in some cases it's invisible, in some case it's NULL, in some cases it's both, `purrr::walk` returns invisibly its first input. `x <- walk(1:3,log);x` or `iris %>% walk(~print(class(.))) %>% head`

Answer (score 16):

An option is `invisible`

```
invisible(lapply(N.seq, print))
#[1] 1
#[1] 2
#[1] 3
#[1] 4
#[1] 5
```

---

If we want to convert the `vector` to `list`,

```
as.list(N.seq)
```

Comment: I'm aware of how to use `as.list()` but as far as I can tell it doesn't make a difference in this context?

Comment: @jeanquilt  Anyway, your question was about how to suppress the printing with `lapply`

Comment: Yes and wrapping it with `invisible()` works, but since `lapply()` works for lists and vectors, I don't really understand why I would need to use `as.list()`.

Comment: @jeanquilt  Because I thought, you want to create a list from vector